# Realizar a un Max una subconsulta

Tags: sql-server

Tengo un problema, ya que cuento con una tabla la cual tiene los campos de iva, precio, nombreproducto, fecha, lo que deseo es obtener el maximo, a partir de una fecha, y me lo realiza, pero ahora necesito que despues de obtener el precio maximo verifique si el iva esta en 0 o en 1, si esta en 1 me lo multiplique por 1.16 y si esta en 0 no le realize nada. Este es el codigo que estoy tratando de utilizar.

```
select MAX(CASE WHEN iva='1' then Precio*1.16 end)as Precio from Gastos 
 WHERE NombreConcepto = 'REFRESCO'and FechaGasto>='20170101'
```

Este codigo me obtiene el maximo pero que tiene iva, y si hay otro precio mas alto que no tenga iva, lo excluye, primero quiero que me tome el maximo a la columna Precio, despues vea si tiene iva lo multiplique por 1.16 y si no que asi lo deje... alguna solucion.

Comment: ¿El MAX sería sin el IVA, pero luego para mostrar este valor si lo tiene quisieras que lo muestre con el impuesto incluído? ¿La tabla tiene algún Id?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho si tiene su id, lo primero que quiero que haga es que me saque el MAXIMO, despues vea si tiene iva, lo multiplique por 1.16 y si no que me tome ese maximo nomal, si no tiene iva..

Comment: Te pongo un ejemplo, tienes 100 + 16 de iva  versus 101 sin iva, ¿Cuál sería el mayor en este caso?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Por ejemplo tengo el precio de un producto maximo de 100, pero no tiene iva, entonces me debe de mostrar ese 100, aunque antes tenga el precio mas bajo pero con iva sea mas alto, lo que pretendo es que me tome el maximo, tenga o no iva, y si tiene iva ese maximo me lo multiplique por 1.16, y si no que me pase ese precio de 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podríamos hacer lo siguiente:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT Precio,
     CASE WHEN iva='1' THEN Precio*1.16 ELSE Precio END PrecioMasIva
     FROM Gastos G
     WHERE  G.NombreConcepto = 'REFRESCO'
        AND G.FechaGasto>='20170101'

)
SELECT  MAX(T1.PrecioMasIva)
    FROM CTE T1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(Precio) MaxPrecioSinIva
            FROM CTE
        ) T2
        ON T1.Precio = T2.MaxPrecioSinIva
```

Detalle:

- Usamos una [CTE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) para construir una consulta de los gastos con un `Precio` bruto y un `Precio mas iva`
- Aprovechando luego la [CTE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql), recuperamos aquellos casos dónde el `Precio` sea igual al `Precio Máximo sin Iva`
- Por último hacemos un `MAX()` del `Precio más Iva` (`Precio` bruto si no tiene iva) para obtener finalmente el valor buscado.

Ten en cuenta que el resultado privilegia los casos que tienen IVA, por ejemplo si tuvieras dos gastos de 100$, uno con iva y otro sin él, el valor máximo de `Precio` sería 100 lo cual coincidiría con los dos gastos, pero finalmente el valor máximo mostrado sería 116$

Comment: Ya quedo muchas Gracias, no quedaba pero cheque busque ejemplos y te falta el "AS" después del CTE

Comment: Efectivamente se me escapó

Answer (score 0):

Solo hace falta que involucres el precio sin iva en la clausula `ELSE`

```
select MAX(CASE WHEN iva='1' then Precio*1.16 else Precio end)as Precio from Gastos WHERE NombreConcepto = 'REFRESCO'and FechaGasto>='20170101'
```

o si es es MAXIMO y despues aplicar iva

```
select top 1 CASE WHEN iva='1' then Precio*1.16 else Precio end as Precio from Gastos WHERE NombreConcepto = 'REFRESCO'and FechaGasto>='20170101' order by Precio desc
```